# Submit info and then open new webpage in button. Multiple actions using Form type = submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

How can I submit entries to my db and then open a link to a new page? In my situation I need to submit information filled out on a form to the DB and then open to a page that says thank you all in one click!

Here is what I have for the form portion minus the stuff in the middle

```
<form id="rent_form" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method='post' >

Stuff 

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="location.href='thankyou.php'" >
```

And the onclick does not work.

Mahalo in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect to a success page using php if the submission is successful.

You can use header to redirect: `header("Location: http://yoursite.com/success");`

Alternitvely you could use AJAX to submit the data, and then in the success of your AJAX call redirect like this: `window.location.replace("http://yoursite.com/success")`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the target attribute of the form tag to redirect the response from the action page to a new window i.e add  `target='_blank'` to your form tag and have the response from your form submission be the HTML you want to display in the new page. This would save a redirect, I guess, at least.